# How would I make a Javascript timer that goes off once a day

Tags: javascript, web, timer, alert

What I would like is a timer in Javascript that goes off once a day at 2:00AM and when the timer went off there would be a alert. I'm just not sure how to do that.

P.S. I'm terrible at Javascript so if you could could you leave the whole script not just what to do :)

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please review the [faq]. It's important to show [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so that we can give you better contextual information.

Comment: You're going to leave a computer with a browser running 24/7 just to flash up a message in the middle of the night? Have I missed something here?

Comment: Use setTimeout with a bias correct to fire each hour (do this each hour to account for daylight or time changes); if it is the correct hour, run said task. That being said, I'm not sure how practical it is ..

Comment: Check what time it is, `var date = new Date(); date.getHours()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
function alarm() {
  alert('my alert message');
  setAlarm();
}

function setAlarm() {
  var date = new Date(Date.now());
  var alarmTime = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 2);
  if (date.getHours() >= 2) {
    alarmTime.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  setTimeout(alarm, alarmTime.valueOf() - Date.now());
}
setAlarm();
```

Comment: `setAlarm` is not in the scope of `alarm`. Also, why the timeout of 1s?

Comment: @Bergi - You are right about the scope. And there is no good reason for the extra timeout, especially as alert blocks anyway.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

For a javascript web page to put up a prompt at a particular time in the future, you will have to leave a browser running with that page being displayed.  Javascript from web pages in a browser only runs in pages that are currently open in the browser.  If that's really what you want to do, then you can do so like this:

```
// make it so this code executes when your web page first runs
// you can put this right before the </body> tag

<script>
function scheduleAlert(msg, hr) {
    // calc time remaining until the next 2am
    // get current time
    var now = new Date();

    // create time at the desired hr
    var then = new Date(now);
    then.setHours(hr);
    then.setMinutes(0);
    then.setSeconds(0);
    then.setMilliseconds(0);

    // correct for time after the hr where we need to go to next day
    if (now.getHours() >= hr) {
        then = new Date(then.getTime() + (24 * 3600 * 1000));    // add one day
    }

    // set timer to fire the amount of time until the hr
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(msg);
        // set it again for the next day
        scheduleAlert(msg, hr);
    }, then - now);
}

// schedule the first one
scheduleAlert("It's 2am.", 2);
</script>
```

Comment: Notice that `setTimeout` is highly inaccurate over hours. Also, to add one day you really should *add 1 day* instead of adding 86400000 ms.

Comment: @Bergi - if `setTimeout()` is not completely accurate, do you have a better solution that answers the question?

Comment: As @user2246674 suggested, you could use multiple smaller timeouts which adjust themselves. However, actually I'm unsure now whether the inacurracy of `setTimeout` was in general or only for (unadjusting) sequences. +1 for a working solution :-)